# Using curl with a https proxy

Tags: proxy, https, curl

I have setup a squid proxy so that it listens on a HTTPS port instead of the usual HTTP port, in order to have encrypted communication between the client and the proxy itself.

While I have been able to configure other tools such as Firefox to use said proxy, I am unable to do the same with cURL. Regardless of how I set the proxy (environment variables, command line arguments...) cURL insists on trying to connect through plain HTTP.

Looking at [cURL documentation for proxies](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-x), it seems that only SOCKS or plain HTTP is supported. Can anybody confirm this ? If so, there is any other similar tool that supports a proxy running on a HTTPS port ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to wait some weeks, because this feature will be included in the next version which should be release on 21st of December https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2016/11/26/https-proxy-with-curl/